# Permanently write a value into a PCR register for TPM 1.2

Tags: linux, tpm

I have system with `TPM 1.2` installed on it. Currently, I'm using tpm-tools to initialize this TPM. With the command

`tpm_extendpcr -p 23 tpm-pcr.key`

I can write a value into a PCR which works fine.

After rebooting the system, the corresponding PCR register is empty again. Is there a way that can help me to permanently write a value into a PCR register?

Answer (score 0):

All PCR's are inherently volatile. The only way to "permanently" write a value in one is to configure your boot process to perform the write at every boot.